# Python Spacy error: RuntimeError: Language not supported

Tags: python, dictionary, entity, spacy

I am going to add new entities to the own spacy data model "mymodel". Before I have installed "mymodel" using this [tutorial](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#usage) and it was working good. When I want to use "mymodel" to add new entities I have a misunderstanding. Please, help me

Here is my code:

```
import plac

from spacy.en import English
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('mymodel')

def main(out_loc):
    nlp = English(parser=False) # Avoid loading the parser, for quick load times
    # Run the tokenizer and tagger (but not the entity recognizer)
    doc = nlp.tokenizer(u'Lions and tigers and grizzly bears!')
    nlp.tagger(doc) 

    nlp.entity.add_label('ANIMAL') # <-- New in v0.100

    # Create a GoldParse object. This should have a better API...
    indices = tuple(range(len(doc)))
    words = [w.text for w in doc]
    tags = [w.tag_ for w in doc]
    heads = [0 for _ in doc]
    deps = ['' for _ in doc]
    # This is the only part we care about. We want BILOU format
    ner = ['U-ANIMAL', 'O', 'U-ANIMAL', 'O', 'B-ANIMAL', 'L-ANIMAL', 'O']

    # Create the GoldParse
    annot = GoldParse(doc, (indices, words, tags, heads, deps, ner))

    # Update the weights with the example
    # Here we iterate until we get it entirely correct. In practice this is probably a bad idea.
    # Note that we've added a class to the existing model here! We "resume"
    # training the previous model. Whether this is good or not I can't say, you'll have to
    # experiment.
    loss = nlp.entity.train(doc, annot)
    i = 0
    while loss != 0 and i < 1000:
        loss = nlp.entity.train(doc, annot)
        i += 1
    print("Used %d iterations" % i)

    nlp.entity(doc)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.label_)
    nlp.entity.model.dump(out_loc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)

**Error of output:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vv/webapp/dic_model.py", line 7, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('mymodel')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 26, in load
    lang_name = util.get_lang_class(name).lang
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 27, in get_lang_class
    raise RuntimeError('Language not supported: %s' % name)
RuntimeError: Language not supported: mymodel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `spacy.load()` currently expects either a language ID (e.g. `'en'`), or a [shortcut link](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#usage) to a model that tells spaCy where to find the data. Because spaCy can't find a shortcut link, it assumes that `'my_model'` is a language, which obviously doesn't exist.

You can set up a link for your model like this:

```
python -m spacy link my_model my_model # if it's installed via pip, or:
python -m spacy link /path/to/my_model/data my_model
```

This will create a symlink in the `/spacy/data` directory, so you should run it with admin permissions.

Alternatively, if you've created a [model package](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/saving-loading#generating) that can be installed via pip, you can simply install and import it, and then call its `load()` method with no arguments:

```
import my_model
nlp = my_model.load()
```

In some cases, this way of loading models is actually more convenient, as it's cleaner and lets you debug your code more easily. For example, if a model doesn't exist, Python will raise an `ImportError` immediately. Similarly, if loading fails, you know there's likely a problem with the model's own loading and meta.

---

Btw: I'm one of the spaCy maintainers and I agree that the way `spacy.load()` currently works is definitely unideal and confusing. We're looking forward to finally changing this with the next major release. We're very close to releasing the first alpha of v2.0, which will solve this problem more elegantly, and will also include a lot of improvements to the training process and documentation.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and would be happy to receive some clarification on this. I'm following this script https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py and with `save_model` method, I create a folder `spaCy_NER` with files `config.json` and `model`, and a subfolder called `vocab` in it. I tried providing both `path/to/spaCy_NER/model` and `path/to/spaCy_NER/` as the first argument to `python -m spacy link`. But I receive the same RuntimeError in both cases. Would you have any suggestions?